# Automorphisms of cubic nodal curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves

How to calculate the automorphism group of the nodal cubic curve $y^2=x^3+x^2$ ? Should I use the rationality of this cubic curve ?

Comment: Yes, since the automorphism group is that of the function field of the curve.